# Iterate through list and return none if not found in other list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to iterate through my list "sents". If my other list "food" contains an element in list "sents", I want to append the value from list "food" to "result", and if it doesn't, append none.

What I have so far is:

`result = []`

`sents = ['I love pizza. its my favorite', 'lets go get a sub', 'I just want a big fat steak']`

`food = ['sub', 'pizza', 'burger', 'noodles', 'candy']`

I know this should be simple, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. Ive tried to do the following:

```
for x in sents:
    for z in food:
        if z in x:
            result.append(z)
        else:
            result.append("None")
```

But this obviously appends an element for each list item in food.

I'm trying to get my "result" list to look like is:

`result = ['pizza', 'sub', 'none']`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You must make an attempt to write code to have a specific coding problem as this site requires.

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to parse through your `sents list` and look for the keywords (`food`).
After finding those keywords, you can append them to the result list.
That's my perspective, coming from another Programming Language.
You'll have to implement this theory to Python.
(I would comment but not enough Reputation points)

Comment: Thanks for the input Renan!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this..

```
result = []

sents = ['I love pizza. its my favorite', 'lets go get a sub', 'I just want a big fat steak']

food = ['sub', 'pizza', 'burger', 'noodles', 'candy']

for lines in sents:
     flg = 0
     for items in food:
         if items in lines:
              result.append(items)
              flg=1
     if flg==0:
         result.append('None')

print(result)
# result = ['pizza', 'sub', 'none']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Result = list([x if sents.find(x) else 'none' for x in food])
```

#updated for string.find()
#also, does not account for case differences

Comment: Hi, this doesn't appear to work either. This results in:

result = ['none', 'none', 'none', 'none', 'none']